# How show a relevent section with in large text page in android

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

I am developing a android application in which it having Userguide Page, which has all the help content for whole App. Now from any screen this page will open and it will show the respective content i.e. from specified position.

Currently i am showing this help content in webview by making a html page, and respective help content will show using the Anchor tag in html. i have taken response from [this](http://freepages.computers.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~pasher/anchors.htm) link.

It is not working proper way.

is there any better way to do this? please share your ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Ur html content is configured inside application itself (in assets folder) ? or loading an external link ?

Comment: I have made a html file, and resided inside the asset folder i.e. inside the application.

Comment: then i don't understand why you are going after anchor tag, just load that directly in webview like below:                      `final String baseUrl = "file:///android_asset/help.html#helplinkcontacts";
final WebView helpTextView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.help_dialog_text);
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        helpTextView.loadUrl(baseUrl);
    }
}, 400);`

Comment: Thank you very much for ur response, let me implement it again.

Comment: one thing, first try without putting timer code, it will work

Comment: Thanks a lot Zoombie, resolved my issue with Timer Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem can be when you place webview inside scrollview, check link here: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039555/android-webview-anchor-link-jump-link-not-working)