# Galaxy Nexus html anchor to different file

Tags: android, webview, anchor

I'm creating an app that uses several local html files (all within the assets directory).  When I create an anchor in file foo.html and create a link to that anchor in bar.html and then view it on my Galaxy Nexus, my webview says that the webpage is not available.

I'm fairly certain that the html has been done correctly.  The w3c HTML5 validator passed it, the navigation works properly when I view the webpages on my computer, and the app works when using a motorolla droid running 2.2.3 instead of the Nexus.

Anchors work when the anchor and link to it are within the same html file, and the pages load just fine when anchors are not included in the links (though of course, not in the spot I'd like them to be at).

If somebody has a solution to this or a different method of doing this I'd be happy to hear it.

In my research I found that there was a bug in the Android OS filed for something similar, but it is marked released, so I doubt that is it.  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

And there is a similar question here, [Android Webview Anchor Link (Jump link) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039555/android-webview-anchor-link-jump-link-not-working), but I don't have any scroll views.

Here is my only activity:

```
package com.me.Foo;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
//import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Foo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    WebView browser;
    public static final String RDR = "RDR";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.forwardButton)).setOnClickListener(this);

        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/table_of_contents.html");
        browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/game_parameters.html#2.9");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.backButton: 
            Log.d(RDR, "Back button pressed.");
            if(browser.canGoBack())
                browser.goBack();
            break;
        case R.id.forwardButton:
            Log.d(RDR, "Forward button pressed.");
            if(browser.canGoForward())
                browser.goForward();
            break;
        default:
            Log.d(RDR, "ERROR!  That button click is not handled.");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/naviagtionLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="@string/backward" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/forwardButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="@string/forward" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/naviagtionLayout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.