# How to scroll to a named anchor in WebView url?

Tags: android, android-webview, uri-fragment

I'm having a compatibility problems opening a locally stored page on a specific named anchor  in Android'd WebView. Currently I'm using simply

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page.html#fragment");
```

which works fine on my 4.1 device but users of other devices keep complaining about it not working.

For example on **4.0.3** Opening the page without the [url fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_fragment) `#fragment` part opens fine but with it user gets a "*Webpage not available*" error.

I've also tried opening the fragment with a two calls to the `loadUrl(String)` method, first without then with fragment. Also using JavaScript to change page's location.

What more could I try?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039555/android-webview-anchor-link-jump-link-not-working

Comment: @Michaël you might want to check out this [meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158228/148672)

Comment: @Fortega, thanks for the link! The strange thing is that while many other report that WebView is simply ignoring the fragment, in my case it fails to load the page if I add fragment to a working url!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#section-3.10) doesn't specify URL fragment portion for `file://` scheme. File URI consists of `file://`, hostname and path -- and that's it.

Thus, anchors in file URIs **should not be supported**. But for some reason, Android does support them since Jelly Bean. If you want them to work on Ice Cream Sandwich too:

```
private static String BASE_URL = "file:///android_asset/";

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        try {
            if (url.startsWith(BASE_URL) && url.contains("#")) {
                url = url.replace(BASE_URL, "");
                InputStream is = getAssets().open(url.substring(0, url.indexOf("#")));
                return new WebResourceResponse("text/html", "utf-8", is);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e("DKDK", "shouldInterceptRequest", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```