# Jump to anchor from button

Tags: android, html, button, webview, anchor

What's the better solution to navigate to a certain point of a html page in a webview using android native buttons?

Is it possible to navigate html anchors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using anchors like this:

```
<a href="#first">First section</a>
```

And then in your button's OnClick handler make your webview navigate to: `http://yoururl.com/page.html#first`

Does that work?

It seems there are some issues when the `WebView` is inside a `ScrollView`, you can read about it here: [Android Webview Anchor Link (Jump link) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039555/android-webview-anchor-link-jump-link-not-working)