# Anchor navigation not working on Samsung Android devices

Tags: android, android-webview, anchor, samsung-mobile, epub

I'm developing an Android app for reading epub books and I use WebView to display the chapter of the book. Inside the book there are internal links with an anchor. (*file://some_path/some_file.html#some_hash*). When the user clicks on this internal link the WebView goes to the required anchor on all phones except all **Samsung devices**.

Comment: Could you provide some specific error, or output?

Comment: The problem is that there are no any specific output. When you click the link it scrolls to wrong place. So actually it works but not as it is supposed to work.

Comment: This might be the problem you are having: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8317764/825364

Comment: @SteveTauber unfortunately, my `WebView` is inside of a `RelativeLayout`, not a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Would you mind adding a bit of the code to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to provide some custom webviewclient, try this, it may help:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
```

...
...

```
public class MyCusomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public HelloWebViewClient() {}

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```